# Open a MacOS application using the hyperref run command without Terminal showing up

Tags: hyperref, mac

I want to open the MacOSX application Photo Booth (starting the iSight camera) from a link in a presentation pdf file. I use the `hyperref` command

```
\href{run:photoscript}{Link text}
```

to call 'photoscript', which contains a single line:

```
open -a Photo\ Booth
```

The application opens alright, but the undesired effect is that a Terminal window appears with

```
/Users/me/photoscript ; exit;
logout

[Process completed]
```

How can I prevent this Terminal window from showing up?

Comment: I think this question isn't part of LaTeX. I think a mac-forum is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're only doing this with OS X, you could use Applescript for your command.

Open the AppleScript Editor (found in the Utilities folder) and make the following script:

```
tell application "Photo Booth" to activate
```

Save this as an application, and then make your link:

```
\href{run:photoscript.app}{PhotoBooth}
```